# Using Laplace Transform to solve a equation with piecewise function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using Laplace Transform to solve$$y''+4y=f$$ Where $y(0)=0, y'(0)=-1,$ and:$$f(t)=\begin{cases}\cos(2t)&\text{if $0\le t \lt \pi$}\\0 &\text{otherwise}\\\end{cases}
$$

Do I need to solve the question on different interval of $f$? If so, how to tansform back?
what is the integral interval for $s$ in the inverse transform?

Answer (score 2):

Before we worry about the inverse Laplace transform, let's first determine take the Laplace transform of your ODE.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{\ddot{y}+4y\}(s) &= \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)\\
s^2Y(s)+4Y(s)-sy(0)-\dot{y}(0) &= \int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
Y(s)(s^2+4)+1&= \int_0^{\pi}\cos(2t)e^{-st}dt + \int_{\pi}^{\infty}0\cdot e^{-st}dt\\
Y(s)(s^2+4) &= \frac{s(1-e^{-s\pi})}{s^2+4}-1\\
Y(s) &= \frac{s(1-e^{-s\pi})}{(s^2+4)^2}-\frac{1}{s^2+4}
\end{align}
Now let's consider the inverse Laplace transform.
\begin{align}
y(t)&=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{se^{st}}{(s^2+4)^2}ds-\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{se^{s(t-\pi)}}{(s^2+4)^2}ds\\
&-\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+4}ds\tag{1}
\end{align}
The first and third integrals of equation $(1)$ should be no trouble and evaluate to
$$
\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}(t-2)
$$
since the first integral has two poles of order two at $s=\pm 2i$, and for the third integral, two poles of order one at $s=\pm 2i$. Let's consider the second integral then. In the time domain, we will have a problem with convergence if $e^{s(t-\pi)}\to\infty$; therefore, we need $s(t-\pi)<0\iff t<\pi$ which leads to the shifted unit step function $\mathcal{U}(t-\pi)$. The second integral is then 
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{se^{s(t-\pi)}}{(s^2+4)^2}ds &=-\lim_{s\to 2i}\frac{d}{ds}(s-2i)^2\frac{se^{s(t-\pi)}}{(s^2+4)^2}\mathcal{U}(t-\pi)\\
&-\lim_{s\to -2i}\frac{d}{ds}(s+2i)^2\frac{se^{s(t-\pi)}}{(s^2+4)^2}\mathcal{U}(t-\pi)\\
&=-\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}(t-\pi)\mathcal{U}(t-\pi)
\end{align}
Combining the result we have that
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}(t) = \frac{\sin(2t)}{4}(t-2-(t-\pi)\mathcal{U}(t-\pi))
$$

Comment: Apologies for bringing this back up, but why do we have convergence issues with the second integral but not with the first and third? Why does the step function solve this problem?

Comment: @FrankLee $e^{s(t - \pi)}$ goes to infinity when s goes to infinity; that is, this integral would be unbounded.

Comment: but so does $e^{st}$? And doesn't $e^{s(t-\pi)}$ go to infinity when $s\rightarrow -\infty$ if $t-\pi < 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The Laplace transform for $f(t)$ is defined as

$$F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}\ dt.$$

For your function, $f(t) \equiv 0$ for $t \ge \pi$. As such, $\int_\pi^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\ dt - \int_\pi^\infty 0\ dt = 0.$